# Database does not have any mapping information Symfony2 Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, metadata

NOTE: Its not a Duplicate issue cause I have tried everything I get on google but nothing have helped us.

I am trying to import Tables using Doctrine Reverse Engineering tool, but I m getting this message:

> Database does not have any mapping information.

My Connection Details in Config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     localhost
                port:     null
                dbname:   pixel_ashish
                user:     root
                password: abc123
                charset:  UTF8
                schema_filter: ~^(?!some_table1|some_table2)~
    orm:
            default_entity_manager:  default
            auto_generate_proxy_classes:  true
            proxy_dir:            "%kernel.cache_dir%/doctrine/orm/Proxies"
            proxy_namespace:      Proxies
            resolve_target_entities: []
```

What I have tried So Far:

1. Running php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
   gives same error
2. Tried to convert mapping also which does not make any sense cause mappings are not there but still tried didn't worked out.
3. Created a new project and tried above given configuration didn't worked.

Now I am out of ideas please help me to solve this.

Comment: Did you try to add `auto_mapping: true` under `orm` section?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some mapping information in your config.

You can do it by passing `auto_mapping: true` under `orm` section:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        auto_mapping: true
```

or by manually defining it under `orm` section:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    YourBundleName:
                        type: "xml"
                        dir:  "Entity"
                        prefix: "Your\BundleName\Entity"
```

Comment: add auto_mapping: true then clear the for prod or dev before testing